# What is the best way to read and write cXML documents in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, cxml-commercexml

I know this is a vague open ended question. I'm hoping to get some general direction.

I need to add cXML punchout to an ASP.NET C# site / application. This is replacing something that I wrote years ago in ColdFusion.

I'm a reasonably experienced C# developer but I haven't done much with XML. There seems to be lots of different options for processing XML in .NET.

Here's the open ended question: Assuming that I have an XML document in some form, eg a file or a string, what is the best way to read it into my code? I want to get the data and then query databases etc. The cXML document size and our traffic volumes are easily small enough so that loading the a cXML document into memory is not a problem.

Should I:

1. Manually build classes based on the DTD and use the XML Serializer?
2. Use a tool to generate classes. There are sample cXML files downloadable from Ariba.com.
   I tried xsd.exe to generate an XSD and then xsd.exe /c to generate classes. When I try to deserialize I get errors because there seems to be "confusion" around whether some elements should be single values or arrays.

I tried the CodeXS online tool but that gives errors in it's log and errors if I try to deserialize a sample document.

2. Create a dataset and ReadXml()?
3. Create a typed dataset and ReadXml()?
4. Use Linq to XML. I often use Linq to Objects so I'm familiar with Linq in general but I'm struggling to see what it gives me in this situation.
5. Some other means.

I guess I need to improve my understanding of XML in general but even so ... am I missing some obvious way of doing this?  In the old ColdFusion site I found a free component ("tag") which basically ignored any schema and read the XML into a "structure" which is essentially a series of nested hash tables which was then easy to read in code. That was probably quite sloppy but it worked.

I also need to generate XML files from my C# objects. Maybe Linq to XML will be good for that. I could start with a default "template" document and manipulate it before saving.

Thanks for any pointers ...

Comment: Not a dupe persay, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444116/what-are-the-best-functions-practices-and-or-techniques-to-read-write-xml-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to generate arbitrary XML in an exact format, you should generate it manually using LINQ-to-XML.

Comment: Thanks. Linq to XML was definitely the easiest way to go.